# Craft 3: Prevent craft adding script filename to URLS

Tags: craft3, control-panel, url, htaccess

I'm running Craft 3 with multi-site.

Working well so far, but my hosting doesn't allow me to create traditional vhosts with their own directories and shared upper filesystem.

As such I have an htaccess at my webroot which rewrites the URL based on the subdomain being used.

```
foo.website.com -> server/web/foo
bar.website.com -> server/web/bar
```

This works, but it means the script filenames are actually rendered into the CP URLS.

So my CP URLs are rendering the server path to the script file:

`foo.website.com/foo/admin/...`

I want Craft to think the CP URL is just `foo.website.com/admin` since this loads correctly with the rewrite rule.

Looking at the URL helper, it seems to add the script filename in either way. Is there a way around it?

Thanks!